# Adding user to groups in active directory (using .Net Core on Linux)

Tags: linux, .net-core, active-directory

I'm trying to add a user to a group using nuget package Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard, I followed this link - https://github.com/dsbenghe/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard/blob/master/original_samples/Samples/AddUserToGroup.cs

However I see error - "Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v3839"

Creating the user using this nuget package works fine, but adding to group fails. Are there other ways of adding user to group, for ex. find a group by name and add the user.
Above sample has multiple steps - adding Group's DN to User's attributes *groupMemberShip* and *securityEquals* and then adding User's DN to Group's attributes *uniqueMember* and *equivalentToMe*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was stuck with the same issue today, but not much different than with Directoryservices.
Here is the modified function which works with Active Directory

```
public bool AddUserToGroup(LdapConnection conn, System.String userdn, System.String groupdn)
        {

            // modifications for group
            LdapModification[] modGroup = new LdapModification[1];

            // Add modifications to modGroup
            LdapAttribute member = new LdapAttribute("member", userdn);
            modGroup[0] = new LdapModification(LdapModification.Add, member);
            try
            {
                // Modify the group's attributes
                conn.Modify(groupdn, modGroup);
                System.Console.Out.WriteLine("Modified the group's attribute.");
            }
            catch (LdapException e)
            {
                System.Console.Out.WriteLine("Failed to modify group's attributes: " + e.LdapErrorMessage);
                doCleanup(conn, userdn, groupdn);
                return false;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error:" + e.Message);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```